# Can we have acceleration in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Two masses of equal length are attached to each other with a rope over a frictionless pulley. One of the masses is on an incline surface of 40 degrees. Supposing that the only forces on the masses are the tension of the rope, the friction of the incline surface and the mass and the gravitational force, does it make sense if we assume any acceleration for this situation? I mean, acceleration makes sense if one of the two masses is over-weighed. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it make sense if we assume any acceleration for this situation? I mean, acceleration makes sense if one of the two masses is over-weighed. Is that right?

Yes! It does. Suppose you don't have a incline plane so that both masses are attached with string and string pass through the pulley. In this case, You would expect no acceleration because both masses have downward force which are balance by tension on string.

Now back to original problem, the block which is not on the inclined plane have a gravitational force downward but the other block is constrained to move in the plane and thus only one part that is along the inclined, is to take care of tension. So Yes you would expect acceleration in the problem. It may or may not possibly depend on friction constant whether it will move or not.